# What is the maximum number of Containers, with dedicated throughput (not shared), per database?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Does anyone know what is the maximum number of dedicated throughput Containers that a Cosmos DB database can have?

The official Microsoft documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/concepts-limits) only mentions the maximum number of containers per database with Shared Throughput (which is 25) but I cannot find any information regarding containers with dedicated (not shared) throughput.

Many thanks in advance,
Hugo

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific per database limit on provisioned throughput containers. The only limit is 500 containers per account. You can put those all in one database or one container per database.